# The arithmetic operations in bash date... ¿are reversed?

Tags: date

**Edit: using Amazon Linux:**

Linux ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx 3.14.44-32.39.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 11 20:33:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Output of this command:

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date="2015-07-27 00:11:22"
```

> 2015-07-27 00:11:22

Output of this command:

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date="2015-07-27 00:11:22 + 00:05"
```

> 2015-07-27 00:06:22

Output of this command:

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date="2015-07-27 00:11:22 - 00:05"
```

> 2015-07-27 00:16:22

OMFG is the time flowing backwards? Or an 8th layer issue?

**Edit**: My Amazon Linux is at UTC+00:00 while my Ubuntu local machine is at UTC-05:00. The same commands in Ubuntu show:

> 2015-07-26 19:11:22
>
> 2015-07-26 19:06:22
>
> 2015-07-26 19:16:22

respectively, so `+ 00:05` does not seem to be the time zone.

Comment: Got the same issue on my gentoo.. I'm checking the "coreutils" sources for more details.

Comment: The numbers after after `+`/`-` mean time zone, so `--date="2015-07-27 00:11:22 + 00:05"` means print date 2015-07-27 00:11:22 in a time zone that is 5 minutes *west of UTC*, i.e. 5 minutes earlier: 00:06:22.

Comment: I want to perform date arithmetic. How do I do it?

Comment: Wait! in my ubuntu machine I get "2015-07-26 19:16:22" as result. This means that 00:05 is not the timezone, but the timezone is 05:00 and both things seem to be applied

Comment: @LuisMasuelli print date as a number of seconds since unix epoch with '+%s', grab it in variable with command substitution, and do arithmetic in normal way with `(())` (double parenthesis) in bash.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli you have different local time zones in amazon and ubuntu.

Comment: See the update. I know. I wrote it to clarify that + 00:05 is not a timezone, but the timezone is applied everytime (so, finally, both 05:00 and 00:05 are applied with the respective signs)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli it means how much do you want to shift (east or west) from UTC time zone. To explain it further: if you write `+0` then you will get date converted to UTC, if you write `+1` you will get date converted to UTC plus 1 hour in time zone (minus 1 hour in time/date).

Comment: This means that TWO timezones are applied? The default +00:00 (or +05:00), and the one I add (+00:05)?

Comment: It's not "bash date". The `date` command is unrelated to `bash`, except that you happen to be invoking it from a bash shell. You're probably using the GNU Coreutils `date` command.

Comment: It is irrelevant. Saying "bash date" is more human-readable than saying "GNU Coreutils date", in the way that saying "Python datetime" is more human-readable than saying "Python dateutil library's datetime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source of [parse-datetime.y of gnulib](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=history;f=lib/parse-datetime.y), it seems to be a feature related to the function **time_zone_hhmm**.

First, we cannot use your format to add seconds : `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date="2015-07-27 00:11:22 - 00:05:01"`, I'm having a parse error :

```
date: invalid date ‘2015-07-27 00:11:22 - 00:05:01’
```

Then, according to the header of the time_zone_hhmm function :

```
/* Convert a time zone expressed as HH:MM into an integer count of
minutes.  If MM is negative, then S is of the form HHMM and needs
to be picked apart; otherwise, S is of the form HH.  As specified in
http://www.opengroup.org/susv3xbd/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03, allow
only valid TZ range, and consider first two digits as hours, if no
minutes specified.  */
```

So, looks like you're modifing the timezone, which match the behavior of inverted add/remove time.

Should you want to perform arthmetics on time, you'd better use Epoch timestamps (date +'%s') which are easier to perform calculations on. Moreover, they are based on UTC time, which does not take local timezone of the server you're working on into account.

A timestamp will thus return the same result on USA, Asia or Europe. Then you use this timestamp to display human readable time, which takes the Timezone into account.

Anyway, nice catch. I would never have dug in gnulib source without this nice trick !